# How I can get the result of an equation after applying the value of variable?

Tags: java

I am planing for taking a equation as a input and value of variable as a input and I want to find out the result as per given value on the equation (For ex: the equation can be: x^2+(3x+4y)+y^2.. the value of x=3 , y = 4)

```
Map<String, Object> varsl = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    varsl.put("x", lf);       // Lower value
    Map<String, Object> varsu = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    varsu.put("x", uf);    //Upper Value

fxl = (Double) engine.eval(equation, new SimpleBindings((varsl)));
fxu = (Double) engine.eval(equation, new SimpleBindings((varsu)));

out.println("function value of x lower " + fxl);
out.println("function value of x Upper " + fxu);
```

But the problem is that If user put an equation containing (^) or something like that (ex: x^3) It cant give the correct result.But If I write (x*x*x) instead of x^3 then I am getting the correct result after evaluation.

Comment: you have to write your algorithm. you should not ask this here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at this guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to help you formulate your question. It will probably require you to provide some of the code you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a quick&dirty solution, you can use Java's built-in Javascript engine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine js = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    String expression = "var x = 5\n" + "5*x+1";
    System.out.println(js.eval(expression)); //Prints 26
}
```

It won't be terribly efficient, and you'd need to pre-process the expression to handle exponentiation, but it should work. A better way would be to use an actual library such as [EvalEx](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx).

Either way, make sure you check your input before doing any evaluation. Executing arbitrary expressions from external sources is an easy way to create horrible security vulnerabilities in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your response.Please have a look on my question again.I have added some of line from my code @Malt